# How to run an application inside docker safely

Tags: bash, security, docker

I want to run an arbitrary application inside a docker container safely, like within a vm. To do so I save the application (that I donwloaded from the web and that I don't trust) inside a directory of the host system and I create a volume that maps this directory with the home directory of the container and then I run the application inside the container. Are there any security issues with this approach? Are there better solutions to accomplish the same task?

Moreover, to install all the necessary dependencies, I let to execute an arbitrary script inside a bash terminal running inside the container: could this be dangerous?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because his question seems more suitable to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://security.stackexchange.com/ to me.

Comment: on the other hand there seems to be more people knowledgeable about docker here (only [100 questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/docker) on unix.stackexchange.com, and [10 questions](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/docker) on security.stackexchange.com, over [5900 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/docker) here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you do not give the application **sudo** access you should be good to try it out.

Dependencies are better off defined in the Dockerfile in a clear way for other to see. Opting to run a script instead will also do the job but it's more inconvenient.

Comment: I read that it's better to user Dockerfile, but why? It's only because you can rebuild the same image multiple times or there is a more specific reason? (as far as you know)

Comment: If the application has sudo access inside a container (let's say with an ubuntu image) launched with docker without sudo, is it dangerous?

Comment: For your first comment, as far as I know, it's more about common practice, automation of builds, re-usability (building a Dockerfile using another one you have made) .

For the second comment, I don't have in depth familiarity with docker security issues but I wouldn't suggest a sudo run in it. I tried to search it since it peaked my interest too. A useful 2-part article you can initially read is [here](http://opensource.com/business/14/7/docker-security-selinux)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it looks very interesting :)

Answer (score 3):

To add to @Dimitris answer. There are other things you need to consider. 
There are certain things container do not contain. Docker uses namespaces to alter process view of the system.i.e N/W Shared memory etc. But you have to keep in mind it is not like KVM. Docker do talk to kernel directly unlike KVM(Vms) like /proc/sys.

So if the arbitrary application tries to access kernel subsystems like Cgroups , /proc/sys , /proc/bus etc. you could be in trouble. I would say its fine unless its a multi-tenant system.

Comment: Ok, docker talks directly with the kernel but the applications inside it shouldn't be able to access host resources and directories like /proc/sys , right? What I'm trying to do is a multi-user system in which each user can do whatever he want inside its own container, but I don't want let him to interact (and bother) other users or the host system. Is that possible?